# jQuery $.each() goes one index too far

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

```
tagArray = new Array('a','b','c');
$.each(tagArray, function(index, value) {
    if(typeof value == 'undefined')
        return false;
    console.log(index + " " + value); 

});
```

Given the above code, I get the following response:
0 a
1 b
2 c
undefined

Why is $.each() going one index too far, also, why is my conditional failing this check?

Comment: The code worked perfectly fine for me. I think your problem is not in this snippet. (proof: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnFx/hbuKA/)

Comment: I'm doing this in firefox 6.0, what browsers are you using?

Comment: FF 3.6.20. Check it out here. http://jsfiddle.net/JohnFx/hbuKA/

Comment: Chrome 13, FireFox 6, IE 9, mobile Safari, and my android browser

Comment: @Jay: I'm using FF6 as well and the fiddle works perfectly.

Comment: @Jay : does the fiddle work for you? I am guessing the problem might not be in the code you think it is.

Comment: very strange, yes it worked on fiddle. I ran an empty function via console and i still get an undefined.

Comment: even if I run "console.log('hi')" in the console, it returns an undefined at the end, did this in both firefox with firebug and in chrome 13, looks like a console bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code works fine, and if it was really going one index too far it would output (note the 3):

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 undefined
```

*not*

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
undefined
```

Here is a JSFiddle to prove to you that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/AhdMn/

You must be logging something later in your code that is undefined.

Comment: To answer the final part of his question. The conditional ISN'T failing the check. The value is never undefined in that loop.